# Can localized strings be placed into separate strings.xml file?

Tags: android, localization

In an Android project, the `strings.xml` file currently contains localized strings that are displayed to the user and system strings like Facebook App ID which are not displayed to the user.

The localized strings are regularly updated and exported from a translation platform.

The issue is that every time the localized strings are exported, the `strings.xml` file has to be manually updated by adding the system strings to the new strings file. In iOS the localized string resources files can just be replaced without manual editing because the `Localizable.strings` files are distinct files.

Is it possible to keep localized strings in a separate file, so they can be easily updated by just replacing the whole file?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. In the `res/values/` and `res/values-.../` directories, the filenames do not matter. By convention, we put strings in `strings.xml`, but you are welcome to have more than one resource file containing string resources, where you decide which string resources go in which file.

Personally I would avoid putting API keys in string resources in the first place. They are often only used in one place and, as you point out, they do not need translating, so using string resources for them adds little to no value.

But, if you want two files with string resources, one for user-facing translated strings and one for miscellaneous non-translated strings, you are welcome to do so.